# What does mean the "removeNotification for unknown key" warning from StatusBar on Android 8.1?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo, android-statusbar

I have the following warning in my logcat on Oreo :

```
W StatusBar: removeNotification for unknown key: 0|com.mycompany.myapp|666|null|10061
```

What does this warning mean ?
What are the implications ?
Should I worry about it or not ?

Thank you in advance for your help.